# python file read, write line by line

Tags: python, file, io

I am studying python file I/O. I made a simple program(**main.py**).

My goal is read line by line and write line by line.

```
fstream = open("input2.txt", 'r');
line = fstream.readline()
while line:
    print(line);
    line = fstream.readline()

fstream.close()
```

below are my `input2.txt` file

```
start.
hello world.
hello python.
I am studying file I/O in python
end.
```

when I run python program

> python main.py

Then, result is ...

```
start.

hello world.

hello python.

I am studying file I/O in python

end.
```

That is not the same as I expected.

So I modified the main.py

```
fstream = open("input2.txt", 'r');
line = fstream.read().split("\n")
while line:
print(line);
line = fstream.read().split("\n")

fstream.close()
```

However my program diged into **infinite loop.**

[picture of infinite loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTy2O.png)

To solve this problem what should I do?

---

The result I expected is the following.

```
start.
hello world.
hello python.
I am studying file I/O in python
end.
```

Comment: `import sys`, `sys.stdout.write` instead of `print`

Comment: Try `rstrip()`.

Comment: Don't post Python code without indentation. Badly indented Python code is nonsense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The print function will automatically add a new line character. So

```
print msg
```

will print content of variable msg followed by a new line

If you do not want python to print the trailing new line, you have to add a comma to the end. This will print msg without the trailing newline. And if msg already has a new line which is the case when reading new lines from a file, you will see a single new line in place of double new lines.

```
print msg,
```

If you are using python 3 where print is called as a function, you can specify the end argument. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print

```
print(msg, end = '')
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, use a `with` statement to open the file so that you don't need to close it explicitly. Second, don't use a `while` loop for this; you can iterate over a file directly. Third, use the `rstrip` method to remove any trailing whitespace from line you read (or `rstrip('\n')` to remove only trailing newlines):

```
with open("input2.txt", 'r') as fstream:
    for line in fstream:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        print(line)
```

Comment: I think, you must close the file stream after using

Comment: @SergeyUr No, that's the point of the `with` statement; it guarantees the file is closed, even if an uncaught exception is raised in the body of the `with` statement.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers above; You can also use .splitlines()

```
fstream = open("input2.txt", 'r');
line = fstream.readline().splitlines()
while line:
    print(line[0]);
    line = fstream.readline().splitlines()

fstream.close()
```